# There is no sound after I set the Audio route become speaker That I use AVAudioSession

Tags: ios, objective-c

There is no sound after I set the Audio route become speaker ,I use

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:nil];
to set Audio route, and the volume is max, but it still no sounds

Comment: to be honest, it is not clear what you wanna achieve, one line of code will probably never produce a sound. Any other info?

Comment: In  interactive live app, I connected the Bluetooth headset into the room and the sound came out of the headset. What I wanted to do was, when I disconnected the Bluetooth connection, the sound could be broadcast from the speaker, so I used [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:nil]; to switch the current channel to a speaker, and the log shows that the switch was successful, but there was no sound coming from the speaker or even the receiver, and I was able to get audio and video data, but I couldn't understand why there was no sound.

Comment: I guess there is somewhere in your code a notification or delegate that handles interruptions and that part code should be probably responsible for the state. Cannot say, you should publish more code, otherwise no one can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The specific situation is that in a similar interactive live broadcast app, when the bluetooth headset is suspended, the audio routing is set as the speaker, but after the setting is successful, there is no sound

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry too late to answer,I just wanted to hear the sound from the speakers after I broke the Bluetooth headset, but I didn't actually hear anything, including the Bluetooth headset.
-(void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central { //第一次打开或者每次蓝牙状态改变都会调用这个函数
    NSLog(@"tb8888");
    switch (central.state) {
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnknown:
            NSLog(@">>>CBCentralManagerStateUnknown------tb");
            break;
        case CBCentralManagerStateResetting:
            NSLog(@">>>CBCentralManagerStateResetting----tb");
            break;
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported:
            NSLog(@">>>CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported-----tb");
            break;
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized:
            NSLog(@">>>CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized-----tb");
            break;
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff:
            [self CurrentDevice];
            NSLog(@">>>CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff-----tb");
//            [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
            [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
            break;
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:
            NSLog(@">>>CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn----tb");
            [self CurrentDevice];
            //开始扫描周围的外设
            [_centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:@{CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @NO}];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}